# Overflow with top/bottom padding scrolls general screen

Tags: css

I have a design with 3 (css grid) columns. The second column has nested grid content that needs to vertically scroll, while the other two columns stay their respective height. I gave the second nested column an overflow, but I also need to give it a top and bottom padding or margin. My solution works without the top/bottom padding, but when I add it, it forces a scroll of the general screen, and thus the other columns.

Here is the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n2fole00/cger28v4/

Here is the part of the code that uses the scroll and padding.

```
.section-column-grid-container {
  display: grid;
  align-content: start;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 35px;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 100vh;  
  padding: 35px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.section-column-grid-container > div {
  background-color: pink;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  height:100px;
}
```

How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes to your code and here is the updated fiddle:

[Updated fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/hs5bjrwe/)

Please check and confirm if this is what you are looking for:
Main change I made is:

```
.main-grid-container {
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It's missing the padding in the second column. If I add `padding:35px !important;` to section-column-grid-container, I nearly get it, but there is no padding on the bottom and for some reason the last couple of divs are cut short.

Comment: Changes made were: 1. removed "grid-gap" from section-column-grid-container and added margin for .section-column-grid-container > div instead of giving padding on parent div. Please confirm, if its working now.

Comment: Thanks, that's great. So the problem was grid-gap. I should be able to figure out how to get the even spacing between the elements back.

Comment: It was easy. I just needed to add `padding: 17.5px` to `section-column-grid-container` and `margin: 17.5px;` to `section-column-grid-container > div`

Comment: I also noticed you added `* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
} `. I've never used that before, but reading about what it does sounds like it made a big difference. That will be handy to know in the future.

Comment: Glad to help you!!